# model.fit fails using keras sequential (slice index ### of dimension 0 out of bounds)

Tags: training, keras, autoencoders

this is the most simple model I can think of for my data yet I can't use the fit function, it gives an error.

the desired procedure is to make a simple autoencoder : from 576 nodes to 64 then back to 576

why this doesn't work ?

```
model = Sequential(name = 'sth')
model.add(Input(shape=(576,)))
model.add(Dense(576, activation='relu')
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu') #bottleneck
model.add(Dense(576, activation='sigmoid')
```

model summary gives :

```
┌─────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Layer (type)                    │ Output Shape           │       Param # │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ input (Dense)                   │ (None, 576)            │       332,352 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ dense_4 (Dense)                 │ (None, 64)             │        36,928 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ output (Dense)                  │ (None, 576)            │        37,440 │
└─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────┘
 Total params: 406,720 (1.55 MB)
 Trainable params: 406,720 (1.55 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
```

then compile and then fit :

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=Xdata, y=Xdata, validation_data=(X_val, X_val),
          batch_size= 32, epochs= 50)
```

the Xdata and X_val are numpy arrays of shape (900, 576) and (100, 576) respectively

gives this error :

**ValueError**: slice index 576 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice_576}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](ReadVariableOp_576, strided_slice_576/stack, strided_slice_576/stack_1, strided_slice_576/stack_2)' with input shapes: [576,64], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <576>, input[2] = <577>, input[3] = <1>.

Comment: This stack exchange is for the discussion of AI.  This is likely a programming issue and should probably be asked on stack overflow.

Comment: Dense layer expects 1-D inputs. Your data seems to be 2-D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was an untraceable mistake in one of my Dense layers, and that was I creating the layer and passed the argument *kernel_regularizer=HeNormal()*, instead of *kernel_initializer=HeNormal()*
wasted 3 days of tweaking everything, while every time I was reading that line of code I just read it as *initializer* automatically.